# Casting smartpointers to base class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, casting, smart-pointers

If `class B` derives from `class A`, can I `dynamic_cast` a `shared_ptr<B>` to a `shared_ptr<A>`, and from `shared_ptr<A>` to a `shared_ptr<B>`?

I just ask myself because with a `dynamic cast` you can do something like `instanceof` in Java. And I asked myself if this also works for `smart_ptr`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932629/implicit-conversion-of-shared-ptr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the particular case of casting from a derived class to a base class, there are assignment operators available that do the necessary implicit conversion for you. For the other direction, you can use dynamic_pointer_cast.

```
#include <memory>

struct A { virtual ~A() = 0; };
struct B: A { };

void example()
{
    // derived to base
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = b;

    // base to derived
    std::shared_ptr<A> a2;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a2);
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast for more info on casting operations - there are equivalents for all the usual suspects like `reinterpret_pointer_cast`, etc.